# Android device cannot detect others by flutter_nearby_connections

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, p2p

I'm a student, studying flutter, live in Japan.

I want to connect between several devices, so I tried sample code provided by Flutter on debug mode.
(link: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_nearby_connections)

As a result, I succeeded to connect between ios, but I didn't succeed between Android.Browser device couldn't detect Advertiser devices.

The Android device conditions used are as follows↓

1. Galaxy SC-02L (OS version: Android 10)
2. Google pixel 5a (OS version: Android 12)

Why don't I succeed to connect between Android? The diffence of OS version??
Please tell me the reason, and what should I do.
Thank you for your help.